# DATES: sh: 1: dates_jackknife: not found

Tags: genetics, admixture

I've been trying to run [DATES](https://github.com/priyamoorjani/DATES), a software that estimates admixture time, on my Linux Mint machine but I keep running into problems. This is the code to run the program:

```
./dates -p pardates.txt
```

The program then runs smoothly, but right before it ends it comes into an error:

```
Calling fit!...
dates_jackknife -p pardates.txt -l     0.450 -z Assyrian -r 77  -a >Assyrian:log
**sh: 1: dates_jackknife: not found**
##end of dates:       28.806 seconds cpu      627.270 Mbytes in use
```

I have tried the software on other Linux flavors but it keeps giving the same error, despite the fact I have exported the path to the bin directory every single time. I exported the path with this line:

```
export PATH=/ubuntu/home/Desktop/DATES/bin
```

I've also checked my version of perl script (dates jackknife's script) and it's up to date.

I have contacted the authors about the issue but they told me it's an issue with my environment, which I'm pretty sure is not.

Comment: it would help to see exactly what the authors said, to diagnose the details.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the path should not be 'ubuntu/home/Desktop/DATES/bin'. It should be /home/username/DATES/bin, where username would be your ubuntu ID/name